# Regex not working on IE8?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have the following function which works perfectly on all browsers expect older versions of IE.

```
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex =  /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

How come is this validating as false, even with the following email:

```
mail@mail.co.uk
```

Comment: Fair enough, although my client has IE8 on his office, so imperative to fix it, even if the numbers of clients are so low for this browser. Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the email address coming from? Any funky whitespaces at the start or end?

Comment: No funky whitespaces, just an email form on a website

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug, how can you be sure that your client was using your application correctly?(I have no installed "real" IE8 available, but with IE6 there is no problem , it works even with IE4)

Comment: Not reproducible, at least from the use of netrenderer.com. As cookie monster suggested, it might be due to some strange white space characters that are not recognized in previous version of IE.